# Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my app, the Android Studio throws the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe''
```

Following are the external jar libraries included in project:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile files('libs/fastjson.jar')
    compile project(':pulltorefresh')
    compile project(':circleheard')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.codeparanoia.house"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

I am unable to sort out the problem. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.
Now when I create a new project(Hello World), OMG, the project didn't work!!!

Comment: check all these jars are for android platform..

Comment: @ELITE yes, it is for android platform

Comment: Upgrade to Java 1.8 and this issues should go away. it's work for me

Comment: Have you added the java path properly@CodeParanoia

Comment: @AjitDubey my Java version is 1.8 ..but it`s not work for me...

Comment: @CrazyAndroid yep,i did... .

Comment: @AjitDubey Maybe I need to change my java version?

Comment: I think so because in my case I did same got positive result

Comment: @AjitDubey  OMG...i changed my java version(1.1.8.0_66---->1.1.8.0.92) same Error Message.....Help....

Answer (score 1):

1. Try cleaning your project by going to

   ```
   Build Menu > Clean Project
   ```
2. Restart Android Studio and Rebuild project

   ```
   Build Menu > Rebuild Project
   ```

---

Another solution could be to enable multidex in your build.gradle(app):

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error message, because my computer had anti-virus software installed, it was killing my process `Java.exe`. When I turned off my anti-virus software, it worked.

So try to turn off your anti-virus software!